# Make jade compile to index.php instead of index.html

Tags: pug

How can I make jade compile to index.php instead of index.html?

Comment: Are you actually trying to generate PHP code (and if so, why?), or do you just care about the filename?

Comment: Hi, just the file name. I'm working localy using MAMP. To test typekit fonts I need to open the page using localhost:8888/

Comment: Are you using make to run jade? If so, I'd just use make to rename the file(s) after calling jade, since [I don't immediately see a way to control the output filename(s)](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a17) that jade produces.

Answer (score 0):

Not found a 'config way', but manually in Codekit we can specify the output file and set index.php instead index.html for example.

Answer (score 0):

On CodeKIT go to config and and bottom of page, change the *.html to *.php see the image [image: click here] to see where to change!